# Calling method with linq syntax based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

How do I loop through a generic list and call a method based on a couple of conditions?  I'd like to use linq syntax.  The following doesn't work of course.  Any ideas?

```
somelist.ForEach(i => i.DeptType == 1 && i != null () {MyMethod(someInt)});
```

If that isn't possible, what is the next best method using concise syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Where to specify which records you want to select and ForEach to execute your method:

```
somelist.Where(i => i.DeptType == 1 && i != null)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach( i=> MyMethod(i.someInt));
```

Comment: Does this compile? I believe [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) can only be applied to `List<T>`.

Comment: Good catch.  I added a `ToList()` which should take care of that.

Comment: I disagree with the use of LINQ in this case. It’s more verbose and significantly less efficient (due to the intermediate list) than the traditional `foreach`. The main reason I’m not downvoting is that the OP asked for LINQ syntax.

Comment: Another problem is that the `ToList()` call will enumerate the sequence an additional time. LINQ is meant to be side-effect-free like David B writes in his answer, and that's why LINQ does not have a ForEach extension method. See also [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
//standard style ... since Linq is Functional/side-effects-free
foreach(var x in somelist.Where(i => i != null && i.DeptType == 1))
{
  SomeMethod(x);
}

//anon method style ... for those that must use ForEach
somelist.ForEach(i => {if (i != null && i.DeptType == 1) {MyMethod(someInt);}});
```

Comment: +1: Best LINQ compromise; however, the order of the conditions should probably be swapped.

Comment: Is it OK to not have a semicolon `;` after the method call inside the `if` block in your anonymous method solution?

Comment: Necessary semicolon added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As appealing as one-liner LINQ queries may be, they’re typically associated with operations that do not have any side-effects (e.g. query projection, filtering, etc). In your case, you might be better served with a traditional `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var i in somelist)
    if (i != null && i.DeptType == 1)
        MyMethod(someInt);
```

P.S. Your original condition, `i.DeptType == 1 && i != null`, is ordered incorrectly. The code will still give rise to a `NullReferenceException` since `i.DeptType` is executed *before* `i` is null-checked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
    somelist.Where(q => q !=null)
    .Where(q => q.DeptType == 1)
    .Select(q => MyMethod(q));
```

The resulting collection will contain a list of return values for the original values/method calls that were acted upon.

Comment: Are you sure it works if `MyMethod` has return type `void` (method not returning a value)? I can't see how it could match the required delegate type `Func<,>` (called `Func<TSource, TResult>` in this case).

Comment: No, you're quite right - was an (incorrect) afterthought.  The main purpose was to demonstrate that .Select() can call methods on collection items.  I've removed the offending sentence - thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind, you should make sure you do your null-checks before you access your object's fields, as in the following:

```
somelist.Where(i => i != null && i.DeptType == 1).ToList().ForEach( i=> MyMethod(i.someInt));
```

As someone above pointed out, you cannot call ForEach() on the Generic IEnumerable object returned from the Where() call.  You must first call ToList() to save the results to a Generic List.  I have updated the code above to include that change.